# How to create regex with multiple conditions

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to scan log file to find some substrings.

How to combine conditions below in single regex expression:

- Find substrings "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" but
- Ignore them in substrings "DDD", "EEE"  or "FFF" are present in string.

I tried something like (?!DDD|EEE|FFF)(AAA|BBB|CCC) but was not successful.

Regular expression syntax should be supported by the Java Pattern class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this one:

```
(?!.*?(DDD|EEE|FFF).*?)(?<!(DDD|EEE|FFF))(AAA|BBB|CCC)
```

It seems to work, using these test cases:

```
123AAA //matches
123BBB //matches
123CCC //matches
123DDD //no match
123EEE //no match
123FFF //no match
AAADDD //no match
EEEBBB //no match
```

Explanation:
Don't match if there's "DDD", "EEE", or "FFF" anywhere in the string.

Don't match if there was a "DDD", "EEE", or "FFF" before the matching substring. (I don't know why this is needed. If I leave it out, "EEEBBB" gets a match, and I think it shouldn't. I need to figure this out.)

---

Update:
I think I needed the negative lookbehind because I wasn't considering the context of where the substring match occurred within the line.

Here's a version that doesn't require the negative lookbehind:

```
(?!^.*?(DDD|EEE|FFF).*?$)(?:^.*?(AAA|BBB|CCC).*?$)
```

Seems to work because I'm considering the whole line.

---

Another update. (Can't leave it alone.) This is optimized a bit:

```
(?!^.*?(?:DDD|EEE|FFF).*$)^.*?(AAA|BBB|CCC).*$
```